# OOPS: 500: CHILD DIED

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 on my VPS. I have installed vsftpd from this command:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

with the following configuration:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
use_localtime=YES
```

and the other default configurations. When I connect to FTP using any client, it gives this error:

```
OOPS:500: CHILD DIED
```

P.S.: I mistakenly deleted a file called ftpusers in /etc and I don't know if it's causing the problem. I purged and reinstalled vsftpd, but I'm still getting the same error.

I also tried restarting Apache and vsftpd.

The contents of the ftpusers file is:

```
# /etc/ftpusers: list of users disallowed FTP access. See ftpusers(5).

root
daemon                                  bin
sys
sync
games
man
lp
mail
news                                    uucp
nobody
```

Permissions and owner of ftpuser are:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 May 16  2013 /etc/ftpusers
```

I am connecting to FTP from user `ash`.

Comment: Is there any relevant information in your logs ?

Comment: No, /var/log/vsftpd.log is empty..

Comment: There are other logs to check.

Comment: `OOPS:500: CHILD DIED` - every time you use plain FTP in 2017, God kills a child. ;)

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://major.io/2007/06/14/500-oops-error-from-vsftpd/) suggests a few solutions. The summary is:

1. Does the directory for the user you are trying to login as even exist?
2. Check file permissions for the directory being accessed to ensure that the directory can be read, but also has execute permissions.
3. Check SELINUX.  Might need to disable to get VSTFTPD to work. Not an ideal situation if you need SELINUX active, but at least you will know what the cause of your error is.